# How can I set environment variable for runComment() in Rhino?

Tags: javascript, bash, rhino

Rhino is running in following directory

```
      /aaa/bbb/
```

and I need to launch another bash script in context of another directory:

```
      /xxx/zzz/script.sh
```

with all environment variable of its directory, especially PWD.

e.g. output of:

```
      runCommand("pwd", {env{pwd:"/xxx/zzz/"}});
```

should be:

```
      /xxx/zzz/
```

How can I properly define the environment variable? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing the correct syntax for the options object. Here's the example from [the rhino shell documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Shell#runCommand):

```
js> runCommand("sh", "-c", "echo $env1 $env2", { env: {env1: 100, env2: 200}})
```

So, you can do:

```
runCommand("sh","-c","cd $mydir && pwd", {env: {mydir: "/xxx/zzz"}})
```

Comment: It seems I missed it thought its complicated example. th@nks